# How can I put some separators between unity launcher icons?

Tags: unity

I really need to put some separator in the unity launcher left bar... I think that could be possible to add some links to a program that simply do nothing so we only need to change it's icon to a separator-like icon... How can I do this?

Comment: but separator will take same size as of other launchers on unity panel. Do you allow this behavior?

Comment: I would have preferred that they occupy less but I don't know how to do this... if you know other solutions please let me know

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just create launcher

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/separator.desktop
```

and paste following details in gedit.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Icon=/path/to/icon.png
Exec=/bin/true
Name=Unity Separator
```

then hit <kbd>Super</kbd> and search for Unity Separator and put it on Unity Panel
Remember, It will consume same space as of other launcher size on Unity Panel.

Answer (score 2):

I solved. I just created some shortcuts with empty command and changed the icon. This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Didn't you just implement what virpara had in his [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/148147/50641)

Comment: I read his answer only after I made it, btw I only made some copies of "My-Wheater-Indicator" (in my desktop) and I changed the properties

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a simple Python script (separator.py) with icon. (see code below)
2. Put it in `~/bin/`
3. Create an `icon.png` and place it in the same directory.
4. `chmod +x ~/bin/separator.py`
5. Launch it. It will appear in launcher.
6. While is running, set it to keep in launcher (right click on icon in launcher).
7. Repeat from 1-6, changing the name to separator2.py etc.
8. Arrange the icons with drag.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

class HelloWorld:

    def delete_event(self, widget, event, data=None):
        return False

    def destroy(self, widget, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def __init__(self):
        # create a new window
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)

        self.window.set_icon_from_file('icon.png')

        self.window.connect("delete_event", self.delete_event)
        self.window.connect("destroy", self.destroy)

        # Creates a new button with the label "Hello World".
        self.button = gtk.Button("Hello World")

        self.window.add(self.button)
        self.button.show()
        self.window.show()

    def main(self):
        gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello = HelloWorld()
    hello.main()
```